# C code works on linux(geany) but not on windows(VS2008)

Tags: c, linux, windows, visual-studio-2008

I've written code for a program in which the user inputs the name of a `.txt` file, and the program prints the alphanumeric words or numbers found in the file (alphanumeric words start with a letter and include letters or numbers). Anyway, when running on Linux using Geany, it works fine, but on Visual Studio 2008 it doesn't (I used [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fU9Guq_-q_Q) to allow VS2008 to compile c code).

The exact problem is that the alphanumerics it shows are like emoticons. There is also an endless loop which I believe might be related to my use of the `fseek` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

union semantic_info
{
    char *s;
    int i;
}SEMANTIC_INFO ;

int yylex(FILE *fp, union semantic_info *sem);
void WaitForEnter(void);

int main()
{
    union semantic_info *ptrs;
    char filename[20];
    int a=0,n=0;
    int k;
    FILE *fp;
    ptrs = &SEMANTIC_INFO;
    printf("Hey you, give me a file name: \n");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    do
    {   
        k = yylex(fp, ptrs);
        if( k==1 )
        {
            printf("%s%s\n", "The type is alphanumeric and it's the: ", SEMANTIC_INFO.s);
            a++;
        }
        else if( k==2 )
        {
             printf("%s%d\n", "The type is arithmetic and it's the: ", SEMANTIC_INFO.i);
             n++;
        }
    }while( k!=0 );
    printf("we found %d alphanumerics and %d numbers! \n", a, n);
    return 0;
}


int yylex(FILE *fp, union semantic_info *sem)
{
    int nextcharacter;
    char lexeme[100]="";
    int k=1, i=0, r=3;
    nextcharacter = fgetc(fp);
    if ( nextcharacter == EOF)
    {
        r=0;
    }
    else if ( isalpha(nextcharacter) != 0 )
    {
        lexeme[i] = (char)nextcharacter;
        //printf("at position %d there is %c \n", i, lexeme[i]);
        while(k==1)
        {
            nextcharacter = fgetc(fp);
            if(isalnum(nextcharacter) != 0 )
            {
                i++;
                lexeme[i] = (char)nextcharacter;
                //printf("at position %d there is %c \n", i, lexeme[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                lexeme[i+1] = '\0';
                k=0;
                sem->s = lexeme;
                r=1;
                fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
            }
        }
    }
    else if ( isdigit(nextcharacter) != 0 )
    {
        lexeme[i] = (char)nextcharacter;
        //printf("at position %d there is %c \n", i, lexeme[i]);
        while(k==1)
        {
            nextcharacter = fgetc(fp);
            if(isdigit(nextcharacter)!= 0 )
            {
                i++;
                lexeme[i] = (char)nextcharacter;
                //printf("at position %d there is %c \n", i, lexeme[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                lexeme[i+1] = '\0';
                k=0;
                sscanf(lexeme, "%d", &sem->i);
                r=2;
                fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
            }
        }
    }
    WaitForEnter();
    return r;
}   

void WaitForEnter(void)
{
printf("Press Enter to continue: ");
//fflush(stdout);
while ( getchar() != '\n' )
;
}
```

Comment: It is very likely that you need to check `nextcharacter` for `EOF` inside `while` loops, as the problem you describe may come from difference on handling error inputs in standard library on Win32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Version - You have assigned the pointer to a local array sem->s = lexeme; inside yylex(). So, when the call is returned back to main, the value in lexeme become void. so, you have to do allocate memory followed by copying of values from lexeme to sem->. Follow the //change comment in the code to see the changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<malloc.h>//change

union semantic_info{
    char *s;
    int i;
}SEMANTIC_INFO ;

int yylex(FILE *fp, union semantic_info *sem);
void WaitForEnter(void);


int main()
{
union semantic_info *ptrs;
char filename[20];
int a=0,n=0;
int k;

FILE *fp;
ptrs = &SEMANTIC_INFO;
printf("Hey you, give me a file name: \n");
scanf("%s", filename);
fp = fopen(filename, "r");
do
{   
    k = yylex(fp, ptrs);
    if( k==1 )
    {
        printf("%s%s\n", "The type is alphanumeric and it's the: ", SEMANTIC_INFO.s);
        a++;
    }
    else if( k==2 )
    {

         printf("%s%d\n", "The type is arithmetic and it's the: ", SEMANTIC_INFO.i);
         n++;
    }
}while( k!=0 );
printf("we found %d alphanumerics and %d numbers! \n", a, n);
return 0;
}


int yylex(FILE *fp, union semantic_info *sem)
{
int nextcharacter;
char lexeme[100]="";
int k=1, i=0, r=3;
nextcharacter = fgetc(fp);
if ( nextcharacter == EOF)
{
    r=0;
}
else if ( isalpha(nextcharacter) != 0 )
{
    lexeme[i] = (char)nextcharacter;
    //printf("at position %d there is %c \n", i, lexeme[i]);
    while(k==1)
    {
        nextcharacter = fgetc(fp);
        if(isalnum(nextcharacter) != 0 )
        {
            i++;
            lexeme[i] = (char)nextcharacter;
            //printf("at position %d there is %c \n", i, lexeme[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            lexeme[i+1] = '\0';
            k=0;
            sem->s=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(i+2));//change
            memcpy(sem->s,lexeme, i+2);//change
            //sem->s = lexeme;//change 

            r=1;
            fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
        }
    }
}
else if ( isdigit(nextcharacter) != 0 )
{
    lexeme[i] = (char)nextcharacter;
    //printf("at position %d there is %c \n", i, lexeme[i]);
    while(k==1)
    {
        nextcharacter = fgetc(fp);
        if(isdigit(nextcharacter)!= 0 )
        {
            i++;
            lexeme[i] = (char)nextcharacter;
            //printf("at position %d there is %c \n", i, lexeme[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            lexeme[i+1] = '\0';
            k=0;
            sscanf(lexeme, "%d", &sem->i);
            r=2;
            fseek(fp, -1, SEEK_CUR);
        }
    }
}
WaitForEnter();
return r;
}   

void WaitForEnter(void){
printf("Press Enter to continue: ");
//fflush(stdout);
while ( getchar() != '\n' );
}
```

Comment: That sounds very logical and it works indeed, now it does print what i expect. The only thing that doesn't work now is that it stucks on the last character before eof and keep printing him. In linux it didn't do that either >_< . How come it can work on linux but not in windows.

Comment: The problem is when you are doing `nextcharacter = fgetc(fp);` again inside `else if ( isalpha(nextcharacter) != 0 )` and `inside else if ( isdigit(nextcharacter) != 0 )` conditions. nextchar's value will be -1 at EOF here which you have not handled as you are simply checking for isdigit and isalphanum. Do handle -1 there.